# Creating an anonymous object that implements an interface with overloaded functions

Tags: typescript, interface, anonymous-types, overloading

I have a TypeScript interface that has a single function called "send" that is overloaded with two allowed signatures.

```
export interface ConnectionContext {
    send(data: ConnectionData): void;
    send(data: ConnectionData, timeout: number): Promise<ConnectionData>;
}
```

I'm trying to create an anonymous object that implements this interface:

```
const context: ConnectionContext = {
    send: (data: ConnectionData, timeout?: number): void | Promise<ConnectionData> => {
        // 
    }
};
```

However, TypeScript 2.4.1 is producing the following errors:

`Error:(58, 15) TS2322:Type '{ send: (data: ConnectionData, timeout?: number | undefined) => void | Promise<ConnectionData>; }' is not assignable to type 'ConnectionContext'.`

`Types of property 'send' are incompatible.`

`Type '(data: ConnectionData, timeout?: number | undefined) => void | Promise<ConnectionData>' is not assignable to type '{ (data: ConnectionData): void; (data: ConnectionData, timeout: number): Promise<ConnectionData>; }'.`

`Type 'void | Promise<ConnectionData>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<ConnectionData>'.`

`Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Promise<ConnectionData>'.`

I know I can do this with a class but I'd rather not create an entire class if there is some way to do this without one.

Comment: I've been having a similar issue, also curious for a general answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out - if a function has overload signatures, type the base function as `any`. This is counterintuitive, but is how TypeScript currently works.

Fixed code:

```
export interface ConnectionContext {
  send(data: ConnectionData): void;
  send(data: ConnectionData, timeout: number): Promise<ConnectionData>;
}

const context: ConnectionContext = {
  send: (data: ConnectionData, timeout?: number): any => {}
};

let a = context.send(1)     // void
let b = context.send(1, 2)  // Promise<ConnectionData>
```

[TypeScript playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20ConnectionData%20%3D%20number%20%2F%2F%20mock%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20ConnectionContext%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20send(data%3A%20ConnectionData)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20send(data%3A%20ConnectionData%2C%20timeout%3A%20number)%3A%20Promise%3CConnectionData%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20context%3A%20ConnectionContext%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20send%3A%20(data%3A%20ConnectionData%2C%20timeout%3F%3A%20number)%3A%20any%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20context.send(1)%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20void%0D%0Alet%20b%20%3D%20context.send(1%2C%202)%20%20%2F%2F%20Promise%3CConnectionData%3E)

See the very last paragraph from the [TypeScript Handbook's functions section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html):

> Note that the `function pickCard(x): any` piece is not part of the overload list, so it only has two overloads: one that takes an object and one that takes a number. Calling `pickCard` with any other parameter types would cause an error.